# Using the alphabet as the counter in align?

Tags: equations, numbering, align

When using the normal `\begin{align}`, thecounter it uses on the right is numerical. If you use the `\begin{subequations}` you get 1a for the first equation in a chapter. My question is this: How do I delete the number, without removing the letter, while also resetting the counter for each new align environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How will you be able to reference these lines?

Answer (score 3):

I'd not overload `align`, but define a new environment for the purpose. Here I abuse the `parentequation` counter used for `subequations`, as it doesn't make much sense to use such variant of `align` inside `subequations`.

Note, however, that you won't be able to reference these numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{alphalign}
 {%
  % save the value of equation
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  % reset equation and make it \alph
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}%
  % start a standard align
  \align
 }
 {%
  % end align
  \endalign
  % restore equation
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}
 }

\begin{document}

An alphabetic align for starter
\begin{alphalign}
a&=b\\
c&=d\\
e&=f
\end{alphalign}
Now a numbered equation
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
and another alphabetic align
\begin{alphalign}
a&=b\\
c&=d\\
e&=f
\end{alphalign}
The end.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
\begin{align}
\text{1st line}&: E^2 = m_0^2c^4  +p^2c^2\\
\text{2nd line}&: \delta S = 0\\
\text{3rd line}&: \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \mu_0j^\nu
\end{align}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
\text{1st line}&: E^2 = m_0^2c^4  +p^2c^2\\
\text{2nd line}&: \delta S = 0\\
\text{3rd line}&: \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \mu_0j^\nu
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]